# Whats does this Sever error mean?

Tags: 14.04, log, error-handling, mongodb

```
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'videoMobileController': Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: could
> not initialize sharding on connection 54.xx.xx.198:27017 :: caused by
> :: mongos specified a different config database string : stored :
> 54.xx.xx.55:27019 vs given : 54.xx.xx.249:27019; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: could not initialize sharding on
> connection 54.xx.xx.198:27017 :: caused by :: mongos specified a
> different config database string : stored : 54.xx.xx.55:27019 vs given
> : 54.xx.xx.249:27019
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
```

Comment: The effect is: **could not initialize sharding on connection 54.xx.xx.198:27017** and the cause is: **mongos specified a different config database string**. That's what i can understand from the error output. Experts on MongoDB can give you a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without looking at logs etc. but the IP addresses involved and the error suggest something like the following:

- You had a mongodb sharded cluster configures in EC2
- The cluster was configured using IP addresses (rather than hostnames)
- The config database (you are only running one, so I hope this is test only and not prod) was on a host that was rebooted, its IP address changed when rebooted
- Because of that change, you restarted your `mongos` process(es) and pointed them at the new IP address by altering the config string at start up
- You did not restart the rest of the MongoDB processes
- Hence the other parts of the cluster still expect the config server to be on the old  IP address and are throwing an error because of the mismatch

Assuming I am close in the description above, the root of your problem is two basic things:

1. If you move config servers and change the hostname (in your case IP address) you have to follow [this procedure](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/migrate-config-servers-with-different-hostnames/).  In particular note step 5: "Shut down all existing MongoDB processes"
2. Don't use IP addresses when configuring a set or a cluster, use hostnames instead, even if they are just in `/etc/hosts` rather than DNS, they provide a level of abstraction that is very useful if you are dealing with an environment where the IP address is transient and you cannot control what IP and instance receives when it is rebooted.

To fix this, you will need to restart the `mongod` and `mongos` processes, basically following the procedure linked in 1 above.  Once all parts of the cluster agree about the IP Address (or hostname) of the config server, this issue should resolve itself.